# How do i move the label behind to the current candle?

Tags: mql4

```
#property       strict
#property       indicator_chart_window
int OnInit(){

   if( ObjectFind("MyLabel") == -1)
      ObjectCreate(0, "MyLabel", OBJ_LABEL, 0, 0, 0);

   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);

}

void OnDeinit(const int reason){

   if( ObjectFind("MyLabel") >=0 )
      ObjectDelete(0, "MyLabel");

}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {

   ObjectSetText( "MyLabel", "$"+DoubleToString(((Close[0]-Close[4])*10000),1), 12, "Times New Roman", clrBlue);
   ObjectMove( "MyLabel", OBJ_TEXT, Time[0], Close[0]);

   return(rates_total);
  }
```

[image: Chart Label]

i want to move the $72.9 to the cuurent candle where i placed the red arrow, not only that i want the label to moving to thee current candle immediately new candle appears?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: AFAIK, `ObjectMove()` didnt work some number of builds ago, hopefully now it is correct. But in case it does not work, you can use `ObjectSetInteger(0,"MyLabel",OBJPROP_TIME,time[0]);` and same with `ObjectSetDouble()` function. Also, if you want to make such operations when a new bar appears (chart operations are quite expensive in MQL4), it probably makes sense to call it only after checking the new bar is detected. Finally, flush all your chart operations with `ChartRedraw();`

Answer (score 1):

You have created a Label object that it's properties are x and y.
You should create Text object (using OBJ_TEXT) so you can move it in time/price axis